# Bringing a grouping from a grouped ListCollectionView into view

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a listbox using as `Source` a `ListCollectionView`

My `ListBox` uses a GroupStyle that looks like

```
<GroupBox Tag="{Binding Path=Items[0].Header}">
    <GroupBox.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Items[0].Header}" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="13" />
    </GroupBox.Header>
    <ItemsPresenter />
</GroupBox>
```

It is applied like so

```
<ListBox.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupHeaderStyle}"/>
</ListBox.GroupStyle>
```

Now I have a button that when clicked is supposed to bring a certain grouping into view (scroll the listbox to the appropriate place)

```
foreach (var groupBox in FindVisualChildren<GroupBox>(this))
{
    if (groupBox.Tag.ToString() == "M")
        groupBox.BringIntoView();
}
```

this works great. However, if in my button press event I change my sort

```
MyVm.MyView.GroupDescriptions.Clear();
MyVm.MyView.SortDescriptions.Clear();
MyVm.MyView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Header"));
MyVm.MyView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Header", ListSortDirection.Descending));
MyVm.MyView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Data", ListSortDirection.Descending));
```

and then immediately again try to BringIntoView the appropriate groupbox, the groupbox is not found. The `FindVisualChildren` finds no groupboxes, only group items.

Full Repro available here:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9417168

any help appreciated!